# Android Studio button onClickListener is not working to switch Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to change the layout when I clicked on a button but it didn't not work

my button is in activity_main.xml

and I want to switch to new_post.xml

here is my code in Activity main class

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try {
            this.getSupportActionBar().hide();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postButton);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this , new_post.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    }
```

my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.finalprofile">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".show_more"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".new_post" />
        <activity android:name=".edit" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

what is the problem?

Comment: I would recommend loading a new Activity or Fragment to handle the new layout, Having multiple layouts in your activity code could lead to null point errors and spaghetti code.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the layout on button click. There is no need to launch Activity again. Just set setContentView(R.layout.new_post) inside onClickListener.

```
 b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             setContentView(R.layout.new_post)
            }
        });
```

But you have to take only one precaution that you will take care of any clicks or work on views that were in activity_main.xml and are not in new_post.xml

Happy Coding